# Best diagram type for display modules interactions

Tags: diagram

I'm starting to design a software, the project manager gave me a list of modules the software needs, and he wants to see the interactions between the modules, ("not the flow", he said), but, I'm not sure of what he wants, (not sure if he is sure of what he wants)
¿any help?

Comment: Maybe ask the manager?

Comment: Just drew lines between the modules, he was happy.